QGIS Raster Calculater Syntax - unable to combine 2 expressions
I have a slope (in degrees) of a DEM where I'm attempting to assign various values to various bands via Raster Calculator.
The individual expressions work, but when combined they do not.
("slope-GDAL@1" >= 61) * 5

works, and
(("slope-GDAL@1" > 40) AND ("slope-GDAL@1" < 60)) * 10

works. BUT
("slope-GDAL@1" >= 61) * 5 +
(("slope-GDAL@1" > 40) AND ("slope-GDAL@1" < 60)) * 10

does not work.
I'm aware my error is very basic.
The error I get is:"Repair Data Source"
QGIS version
3.36.3-Maidenhead
Just discovered the problem/answer!
The issue seems to be that I'm generating the raster "on the fly" rather than "writing layer to disk". When I do the latter the calculation works. Does this mean there is a glich in QGIS 3.36.3-Maidenhead?



Raster calculator output will be always one band. What do you mean by "does not work"?

@user2856 - Do you mean:
(("slope-GDAL@1" >= 61) * 5) +
(("slope-GDAL@1" > 40) AND ("slope-GDAL@1" < 60)) * 10
..as that produced the same error

The issue seems to be that I'm generating the raster "on the fly" rather than "writing layer to disk". When I do the latter the calculation works. Does this mean there is a glich in QGIS 3.36.3-Maidenhead? If so, does it need to be reported?

Can you include a screenshot of the information tab of "on the fly" calculated raster layer properties?

Original source URI: %3Fcrs%3DEPSG%3A3857%26extent%3D3898717.78839999996125698%2C-384873.11859999998705462%2C4058461.25769999995827675%2C-228934.38409999999566935%26width%3D5166%26height%3D5037%26formula%3D%28%2522slope-GDAL%401%2522%2520%253E%253D%252061%29%2520%2A%25205%2520%2B%2520%250A%28%28%2522slope-GDAL%401%2522%2520%253E%252040%29%2520AND%2520%28%2522slope-GDAL%401%2522%2520%253C%252060%29%29%2520%2A%252010%26slope-GDAL%3Auri%3DQ%3A%2FBU%2520Volunteer%2FQGIS%2FIans-Rift-Valley%2F99-LCPs%2FLCP-OLD-NAT%2FLevel%2520C%2520Confirmation%2Fslope-GDAL.tif%26slope-GDAL%3Aprovider%3Dgdal

The problem might be realeted with a drive Q, but seems better to me if you can report it to QGIS developers.

@GabrielDeLuca, what do you mean with "a drive Q"?

Hi @AndreaGiudiceandrea, I mean a Windows file system drive. In the URI shared in the previous comment, it seems like the source raster is located in a path on drive Q and I think the problem described in the post could be related to that. Either because the Q drive may be mapping a remote location, because the temporary file wants to be saved there or for some other reason related to that drive, which I understand would be better to consult with QGIS developers.

The issue seems to be that I'm generating the raster "on the fly" rather than "writing layer to disk". When I do the latter the calculation works. Does this mean there is a glich in QGIS 3.36.3-Maidenhead?
